# How Can I Show sort menu and button excel on datatable

Tags: spring, datatable

This is my data table image and that I want to show button excel and pdf with show entries

[image]

```
$("#listReport").DataTable({
  'aoColumnDefs': [
    {
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': [-1],
    }
 ]
})
```

this is what I want to show with data table

[image]